# xcode ios objective-c mkmapview: compare MKMapView span

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mkmapview

How can I compare the current span of a MKMapView?
I am using the following code:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    if ([[regionsMapView.region.span] doubleValue] < 1.0) {
        NSLog(@"SHOW ANNOTATIONS");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"HIDE ANNOTATIONS");
    }
}
```

But it shows error like this:

```
error: expected ':' before ']' token
confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

And again if i use like below:

```
if (regionsMapView.region.span < 1.0) {
    NSLog(@"SHOW ANNOTATIONS");
}else {
    NSLog(@"HIDE ANNOTATIONS");
}
```

Then it also show error like below:

```
error: invalid operands to binary < (have 'MKCoordinateSpan' and 'double')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*MKCoordinateSpan* is a *struct* which has two values *latitudeDelta* and *longitudeDelta*, which looks like this,

```
typedef struct {

    CLLocationDegrees latitudeDelta;
    CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta;

} MKCoordinateSpan;
```

If you want to compare any of there values. You should use,

```
if (regionsMapView.region.span.latitudeDelta < 1.0)
```

or,

```
if (regionsMapView.region.span.longitureDelta < 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `[]` from `[regionsMapView.region.span]`

Comment: I also did so; But not working.
Please see the edit of the post